# What is the difference between an active today on Google Hangouts and an actual mins or hours online?

Tags: google-hangouts

I noticed some of my friends will show the actual minutes/hours they were last seen active (for example: `active 10 mins ago` or `1 hr ago`). But one friend will show last seen as `Active today`. I know that it was just last seen because there was a green bubble next to the name but when the person logged out, it shows active today instead.

Does that mean the setting for `show when you were last active` was off?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/hangouts/oUkHQaMwCrc;context-place=topicsearchin/hangouts/category$3Ashare-tips%7Csort:relevance%7Cspell:false) has:

> I have noticed for myself that the active + time is when the person has been active within the last 12 hours so it gives you an exact time ago they were on whereas "active today" means they were active more than 12 hours ago and it is still considered your 'today.'